# using react-azure-adb2c when I want to redirect after login I get state mismatch and see a blank page, how to fix that?

Tags: reactjs, azure, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

Using Custom policies and react-azure-adb2c(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c) and SPA in reactjs, the issue is after login (using separate custom policy)I get successfully loggen in, and get id and access tokens correctly stored in session. there is a link on the app to change password which redirect to another custom policy which works fine as well BUT after it's done and gets redirect to the landing page I get State Mismatch error, because the new state comes back empty, any ideas on how to fix it? Also on html it shows You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. BUT when I refresh the page it works as expected

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/320

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan for your reply, I do have a redirect url and it gets redirected correctly but before running the app I get Msal error which looks for some state which is empty, I don't know why it is empty as 'state' is not exposed by the library